# c# equivalent of pascal/delphi procedure of object

Tags: c#, delphi

What is the c# equivalent of the Pascal local callback procedure type defined as:

```
type
MyPascalCallback = procedure(bmpHandle : HBitmap) of object;
```

How does this particular form (procedure() of object) translate into c#?

This is the case I use for the 'usual' Pascal procedure:

```
type
MyPascalCallback1 = procedure(bmpHandle : HBITMAP); cdecl;
```

is translated as

```
public delegate void MyPascalCallback1 (IntPtr bmpHandle);
```

Comment: Do you have a question or are you attempting a self-answer?

Comment: I have a question. How does procedure() of object; translate into c#? I gave example how I do it for a procedure(); cdecl;

Comment: There's not enough detail here. The mention of `cdecl` implies this is interop between C# and Delphi. Is that the case. We need more detail.